# Angular unit testing catchError in Promise

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm testing catchError in Angular service

```
public async getRegById(id, regId): Promise<Reg> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<Reg>(
        `TestURL`,
        {
          observe: 'response'
        }
      ).pipe(
        map(response => {
          return response.body;
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          return throwError(() => err);
        }),
      ).toPromise();
  }
```

my test is:

```
    it('it should throw error', async () => {
      const expectedUrl = `TestURL`;
      getHttpClientSpy.withArgs(expectedUrl, defaultOptions).and.throwError('Test error');
      try {
        await service.getRegById(null, 12);
      } catch (e) {
        expect(e.message).toEqual('Test error');
      }
    });
```

test runs as expected but when I run test coverage
it shows that catchError part of test is not covered

[image]

Comment: what is this getHttpClientSpy

Comment: getHttpClientSpy = spyOn(httpClient, 'get');

Comment: httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);

Answer (score 2):

I think `throwError` is for regular JavaScript error from jasmine.

I think you need `throwError` from `rxjs` since `httpClient` is concerned with observables.

Make the following modifications:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
it('it should throw error', async () => {
      const expectedUrl = `TestURL`;
// return value here and rxjs throwError
      getHttpClientSpy.withArgs(expectedUrl, defaultOptions).and.returnValue(throwError({ message: 'Test error' }));
      try {
        await service.getRegById(null, 12);
      } catch (e) {
        expect(e.message).toEqual('Test error');
      }
    });
```

All of that being said, I would use `HttpClientTestingModule` to test http services. Check out [this](https://medium.com/netscape/testing-with-the-angular-httpclient-api-648203820712) blog. I assume you're not using `HttpClientTestingModule` because of `getHttpClientSpy`.